# Ruby on Rails Carrierwave - files uploaded owned by 'nobody'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm having a very strange issue with Carrierwave. When I upload an image file the file gets uploaded fine, but it won't perform the resize. I've noticed that the uploaded files are owned by nobody:nodate. I assumed that they would be owned by www-data (this is on debian).
Has anyone else had an issue like this before? I'm absolutely baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It wasn't an issue with carrierwave at all. There was a bad clock skew on the server and so that was affecting things for some reason. Once I installed ntp and fixed the issue, the problem with files being owned by nobody/nogroup went away.